# Selecting an element in React in a stateless function component in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
<TextField
    onChange={props.onChangeTextField}
    ref="questionInput"
    style={styles.textField}
    value={props.existingValue}
    fullWidth={true}
/>
```

I was trying to give an input field in a stateless function component to be able to focus it when the component loads like this:

```
componentWillMount = () => {

        this.refs.questionInput.focus();
        console.log('test')

    }
}
```

But I got the error:

```
Stateless function components cannot have refs.
```

So is there a way to focus an input field in React without a ref?

Comment: Just a heads up.  React recommends interacting with the DOM in the componentDidMount.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more code? Which component is the functional component? When exactly do you want to control its focus state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your input component with [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) function. Something like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

const TextInput = React.forwardRef(
  (props, ref) => <input ref={ref} {...props} />
);

export default TextInput;
```

Note that it will add a second argument to your functional component, which you should pass to the DOM element as `ref` prop.

Comment: Not sure this actually addresses the question. But it's not exactly clear what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I think I understand what the author is asking. They expect the ref to have `.focus()` prop as if it was DOM element, but when you pass ref to a component you get component instance instead or a warning in case of functional component. Ref forwarding is useful in those cases where you introduce an intermediate component but also need to be able to access an instance of a DOM element.

Comment: Well, it's a solution to the problem, but the other solution is to create the ref and pass it to the stateless function component.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to change the [functional component into a class](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs).

> You may not use the ref attribute on functional components because they don’t have instances

You should also use the newer callback API to set the ref:

```
ref={ref => { this.questionInput = ref }}
```

Or [createRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) for v16.3.

Adding the `autoFocus` prop to the input component might do the trick if you just want it to be focused on mount:

```
<TextField autoFocus ..restOfProps />
```

Comment: Is it possible to focus the element without a ref?

Comment: Try the `autoFocus` prop. Only for initial focus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However your method of using `ref` is really outdated. You should update to the latest version of React (currently `16.3.2`) and follow the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components)

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  let textInput = React.createRef();

  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />

      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So how do I focus the element?

Comment: What do you mean "how do I focus the element?" Are you talking about controlling the focus state of an element from the parent?

Comment: first sentence in the documentation you link to states: You may not use the ref attribute on functional components because they don’t have instances:

Comment: @maxwell Yes, but "you can, however, use the ref attribute inside a functional component as long as you refer to a DOM element or a class component." The heart of his question isn't "can I put a `ref` directly on a functional component." It's "can I use a `ref` to focus an element inside of my functional component." Which -- yes, he can do. :)

Comment: actually - I guess the parent doesn't matter - yep retracting down vote